# Removing a class constructor results in "not enough arguments for constructor" (recompilation not working?)

Tags: scala, compilation

I ***had*** a Scala class as follows:

```
class ClassA(val name: String) {
  println("this is a class")
}
```

now I ***have*** this class:

```
class ClassA() {
  println("this is a class")
}
```

in my main I ***used*** to declare the class like this:

```
val s = new ClassA("hello")
```

now I declare it like this:

```
val s = new ClassA
```

The issue is that before everything worked fine, but when I remove the name parameter from the object I still get this error:

```
error: not enough arguments for constructor ClassA: (name: String)ClassA.
Unspecified value parameter name.
```

It seems like the class is not compiling, but I recompiled everything.  Is there a way I can clear out all old compile data and start fresh?

Comment: It is hard to tell without knowing the Scala version and which IDE/build system you used.

Comment: I am using the latest scala version, and just >scalac >scala...no ide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read this document http://www.scala-lang.org/node/166 and realized that in scala you run the class not the file.  So, I was just running the regular file x.scala instead i needed to run Main